# Visual basic / sql - Unable to cast types

Tags: sql, vb.net

Ran into this error message while trying to select some records off a table.

My mind is shot right now..
Any ideas? Thanks!

myreader is,

```
Public myReader As SqlCeDataReader
Dim currentMatch(1) As String

cmd.CommandText = "SELECT schoolid,opponent " & _
                  "FROM TEAM_SCHEDULE WHERE seasonid = " & i & _
                  " AND gameid = " & 1 & " ORDER BY id"
myReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
Do While myReader.Read()
    currentMatch(0) = myReader.GetString(0)
    currentMatch(1) = myReader.GetString(1)
Loop
```

[image: error]

Comment: Concatenating SQL the way you are exposes you to [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Educated guess:

`schoolid` is defined as `INT`, but for some reason you are using `GetString` instead of `GetInt32` to fetch it.

```
Do While myReader.Read()
    currentMatch(0) = myReader.GetInt32(0).ToString()
    currentMatch(1) = myReader.GetString(1)
Loop
```

Comment: What is the data type for seasonid & gameid??

Comment: @larryr - Why does that matter? I assume they are also `INT` from the SQL posted and the fact that the query doesn't fail.

Comment: Thanks, not sure why I used string.

Answer (score 0):

why don't use datatable?

```
 Public myReader As SqlCeDataReader
 Dim currentMatch(1) As String

 cmd.CommandText = "SELECT schoolid,opponent " & _
              "FROM TEAM_SCHEDULE WHERE seasonid = " & i & _
              " AND gameid = " & 1 & " ORDER BY id"
 Dim dt as new DataTable 

 dt.load(cmd.ExecuteReader())
```

If you want, you can query result datatable with linq

```
 dim QueryResults = from p as datarow in dt.rows where p.seasonid<10 select p
```

or select a list

```
 dim MyObjList = (from p as datarow in dt.rows select seasonid = p.seasonid,  gameid = p.gameid).ToList
```